# UITableViewCell loading in background and update to specific tableViewCell when finish

Tags: iphone, multithreading, uitableview, uiimage

I want to make tableView like "Sections" in SBS News Australia app. The list is loaded first (the image still show default image when the background thread get the image from url) and after the image is finished downloaded or get from the URL it will update to specific tableViewCell. How i can do that? If i use thread how can i go back to specific index in tableViewCell when performing update view in main thread (performSelectorOnMainThread)?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you finish loading the cell, call [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:<#(NSArray *)#> withRowAnimation:<#(UITableViewRowAnimation)#>] and it will redraw it.  You can call it from the performSelectorOnMainThread method.